# Hyperledger Fabric channel creation, cannot get Channel-ID.block

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I have been trying to create my first network and followed the official docs. But I have been trying to create the channel using following command:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

While it did not gave me any errors I got the following response:

```
2018-02-26 12:59:03.263 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-02-26 12:59:03.263 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-02-26 12:59:03.271 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-02-26 12:59:03.273 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 004 Returning existing local MSP
2018-02-26 12:59:03.274 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 005 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-02-26 12:59:03.274 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 006 Returning existing local MSP
2018-02-26 12:59:03.274 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 007 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-02-26 12:59:03.274 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 008 Sign: plaintext: 0A8C060A074F7267314D53501280062D...53616D706C65436F6E736F727469756D 
2018-02-26 12:59:03.274 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: 17C4AA38A89CFCCCEC5FF13E7F51BC4FF9C23F72E900454F30AE8ABB0A338DF8 
2018-02-26 12:59:03.274 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00a Returning existing local MSP
2018-02-26 12:59:03.274 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00b Obtaining default signing identity
2018-02-26 12:59:03.275 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00c Returning existing local MSP
2018-02-26 12:59:03.275 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00d Obtaining default signing identity
2018-02-26 12:59:03.275 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00e Sign: plaintext: 0AC3060A1508021A06089789D0D40522...B4DCD533B8C5DA311196A1277CDC1204 
2018-02-26 12:59:03.275 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00f Sign: digest: A1BC4CF64450BD26E28303C321E1E43658EF4C377E055121537863F4624BBB5E 
2018-02-26 12:59:03.385 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 010 Returning existing local MSP
2018-02-26 12:59:03.386 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 011 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-02-26 12:59:03.386 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 012 Returning existing local MSP
2018-02-26 12:59:03.386 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 013 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-02-26 12:59:03.386 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 014 Sign: plaintext: 0AC3060A1508021A06089789D0D40522...03C6A8CB79E812080A021A0012021A00 
2018-02-26 12:59:03.386 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 015 Sign: digest: 1803C7715AEA9E1C5DD8D1BEECF639C03233911A3AC437AF83114C91F52EB0D5 
2018-02-26 12:59:03.390 UTC [channelCmd] readBlock -> DEBU 016 Got status: &{NOT_FOUND}
2018-02-26 12:59:03.391 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 017 Returning existing local MSP
2018-02-26 12:59:03.391 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 018 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-02-26 12:59:03.402 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 019 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-02-26 12:59:03.604 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 01a Returning existing local MSP
2018-02-26 12:59:03.604 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 01b Obtaining default signing identity
2018-02-26 12:59:03.604 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 01c Returning existing local MSP
2018-02-26 12:59:03.604 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 01d Obtaining default signing identity
2018-02-26 12:59:03.604 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 01e Sign: plaintext: 0AC3060A1508021A06089789D0D40522...10B3951C861712080A021A0012021A00 
2018-02-26 12:59:03.604 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 01f Sign: digest: 1E71D72F8D5B50472EA46BC372866789252A02AEDC4D5299CD18FD6A0A08DF2F 
2018-02-26 12:59:03.608 UTC [channelCmd] readBlock -> DEBU 020 Received block: 0
2018-02-26 12:59:03.612 UTC [main] main -> INFO 021 Exiting.....
```

So my problem is I don't see any  in the response. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried to join peer to channel?

Answer (score 2):

```
peer channel create ...
```

return a genesis block (a file, mychannel.block in your case) which is supplied in

```
peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

this will join the peer to mychannel.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found out the id after running -ls command. I was assuming that the block id would be returned inside the command response. But it was actually inside the docker containers.

Comment: Now everything is working as expected. Thanks for the helpful comment anyway.